# nginx reverse proxy: set http to be secure

Tags: nginx, tomcat, nginx-reverse-proxy

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name *.my-domain.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/mycert.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/certs/mykey.pem;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;

        proxy_set_header secure true  <----
    }
}
```

The proxied is Tomcat java servlet webapp.

```
 request.isSecure()  return false
```

Any proxy-set-header for setting secure = true, so that

```
 request.isSecure()  return true
```

The web app generates URLs using https or http based on the method request.isSecure().

UPDATE:

Tried:

```
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
```

not working.